# Keep tracking "original" item in RxJs

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I need to access the "original" value of stream.

**My use case:**

1. Iterating list of URLs.
2. Request each URL.
3. handle the response, and at this point, I also need the URL from the first "iteration".

**Sample code:**

```js
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const request = require('request');

// my request method in Rx version
const req = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(request);
const list = [/*list of URLs*/];

Rx.Observable.from(list)
    .flatMap(req) // eq to: .flatMap(url => req(url))
    .map(response => {
        // here I need the response object
        // and the URL I used to request it (the "original" value).
    });
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlatMap has an overload which takes the input and every produced value for you to map:

```
.flatMap(
  url => doRequest(url),
  (url, res) => ({ url, res }) 
)
```